# How to fix, I need to assign the variable to class public variable

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents(abd.json),true);
class myclass{
 public $first_name = $result["firstname"];
} 
?>
```

This is my code 
in other file i will use myclass::$first_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using the `static` keyword

```
class myclass{
  public static $first_name;
}
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents(abd.json),true);
myclass::$first_name = $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer is not correct because every instance of MyClass would have the same value. Here is a "better" solution:

```
<?php 
class MyClass
{
    public $first_name;
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('abd.json'), true);

$user = new MyClass();
$user->first_name = $data['firstname'];
```